# wget-command for downloading more than one page

Tags: command-line, wget

does anybody know the exact command I have to use to download part of a website that consists of more than one page (with wget).
Example:

I want to download a certain page which exists within a forum.
There´s an article dealing with "stderr" within this forum.

The address is : "https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/stderr-umleitungen/"   AND   "https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/stderr-umleitungen/2/" as it consists of two pages.

What I want to do is download both pages with one command, but not the entire forum.
How do I go about typing the correct command?

System: Linux/Lubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, 64bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wget -Ek https://example.com/foo/bar/{,2}
```

The last bit `{,2}` is a [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) which instructs wget to download:

```
https://example.com/foo/bar/
https://example.com/foo/bar/2
```

To download pages 3 through 6, use either of these commands:

```
wget -Ek https://example.com/foo/bar/{3,4,5,6}
wget -Ek https://example.com/foo/bar/{3..6}
```

And there are a couple of really useful [wget options](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html): -E and -k.

-E: If a file of type "text/html" is downloaded and the URL does not end with the regexp `\.[Hh][Tt][Mm][Ll]?', this option will cause the suffix ".html" to be appended to the local filename.

-k: After the download is complete, convert the links in the document to make them suitable for local viewing (i.e., convert relative links to absolute links).

Please read the wget man page and manual for more information.

Comment: Hi TooManyPets. Tnx a lot for your reply. This command of yours works like a charm. That´s really what I was looking for.  Tnx also for the links. As far as the man pages are concerned  I really couldn´t find the right command  for downloading more than one page  "{"     and     "}"     actually never show up  in the man-pages. Greetings. Rosika

Comment: Your're welcome. Please have a look at [these suggestions](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) when you have a moment.